# Powershell equivalent of whos from MATLAB or ipython

Tags: powershell, read-eval-print-loop

In MATLAB or ipython, I am used to typing `who` or `whos` to see a list of variables I have created in the workspace. `Get-Variable` in PowerShell provides a similar function, but it delivers too much information. Is there a way to limit `Get-Variable` to what I have created in the current session, or is there another command that I should use instead?

Comment: You could save the names of all variables at the start of the session: `$initialVars = Get-Variable |% Name`, and then use it to filter other variables later, eg: `function whos { Get-Variable |? Name -notin $initialVars}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Thanks, that certainly works. But it seems too hard?

Comment: Okay. Then don't ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: You misunderstood. I am grateful for your suggestion, and it works. My remark was more about whether the PowerShell designers had considered this use case and designed something concise into the Get-Variable command options or predefined and alias for this usage.